# Navigation Menu Screen Sizes Issue

Tags: html, css

I am working with a navigation menu.  It has no drop downs, it is just a plain old horizontal nav menu.  The problem I am running into is that when the page is loaded on a 1280 x 768 screen the menu text looks noticeably larger which causes the menu items to be pushed down to the next level.  On my 1600 x 900 screen everything looks fine.  I am using Firefox between both PCs.  One PC is Windows 7 one is Windows Xp.  I thought it maybe Cleartype but disabling that did not resolve the issue.  Text spacing was another idea but setting that did not resolve the issue either.  I can post code if needed, but I feel as if I have ruled that out.

```
 <div class="wrapper clearfix">
<nav>
    <ul id="nav" class="sf-menu">
        <li ><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="loans.php">Loans</a></li>  
        <li><a href="checkings.php">Checkings</a></li>
        <li><a href="credit.php">Credit Cards</a></li>
        <li><a href="debit.php">Debit Cards</a></li>
        <li><a href="savings.php">Savings</a></li>
        <li><a  href="member_ed.php">Member Education &amp; Calulators</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="vehicles.php">Vehicles &amp; Homes</a></li>
        <li><a id="last_item" href="">Mortgages</a></li>
    </ul>

</nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 nav{
margin-top: 0px;
height: 30px;
 }


 nav a{
text-decoration: none;
 }

 #nav li{
float:left;
}

 #nav>li>a{
font-family:'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 1.35em;
letter-spacing:.05em;
 }
 .wrapper {
width: 940px;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* Stops Mobile Safari from auto-adjusting font-sizes */
```

}

There is no margin between words so it should really be the same width.

Comment: Please include relevant HTML and CSS styles.

Comment: it sounds like your items are floating without the container having a fixed width, so when your viewport is small it will wrap and when your viewport is big it won't wrap

Comment: Have you specified layout width in pixels and font size in `pt`s? `1pt` is 1/72 inches, which is not always 1 pixel if the screen density is not 72ppi.

Comment: Ok I added my code.  My wrapper is a fixed 940px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this issue. It was really an issue with the web-font that I was using. At different sizes it had different spacing. When I changed fonts I didn't have the issue.